# Player Movement (Jump issue)

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

So, im trying to implement the keys that triggers the movement of the main character  in a game.
here is my code:

```
public class Play  implements Screen{
```

the variables:

```
World world;
Box2DDebugRenderer b2Dr;
OrthographicCamera camera;
OrthographicCamera hudCamera;
private SpriteBatch batch;
private Body toniBody;
private RHContactListener rhcl;
```

the render stuff (note that I have a java class named InputController for the setInputProcessor, it extends InputAdapter and it gots certain keys set for Down and Up states):

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputController());
    RHInput.update();
    camera.update();
    handleInput();
    world.step(delta, 6, 2);


    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    batch.end();

    b2Dr.render(world, camera.combined);
}
```

Here is where the camera is set to an certain zoom

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

    camera.viewportWidth = width/24;
    camera.viewportHeight = height/24;
    camera.update();

}
```

the stuff to be in the screen:

```
@Override
public void show() {
    world = new World(new Vector2(0, -9.81f),true);
    rhcl = new RHContactListener();
    world.setContactListener(rhcl);
    b2Dr  = new Box2DDebugRenderer();

    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    camera= new OrthographicCamera();
```

here is where i defined the objects of my scene, the ground and the player:

```
    ////Box2D////

    //CREATE GROUND
    //body definition
    BodyDef bDef = new BodyDef();
    bDef.position.set(0,-14);//meters
    bDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
    Body body = world.createBody(bDef);
    //shape definition
    PolygonShape ground = new PolygonShape();
    ground.setAsBox(25, 1);//meters
    //fixture definition
    FixtureDef fDef = new FixtureDef();
    fDef.friction= .5f;
    fDef.shape = ground;
    fDef.filter.categoryBits = B2DVariables.BIT_ground;//colision type
    fDef.filter.maskBits = B2DVariables.BIT_can;//matching collision type
    body.createFixture(fDef).setUserData("ground");

    //CREATE TONI
    //body definition
    bDef.position.set(-10,-10);//meters
    bDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    toniBody = world.createBody(bDef);
    //shape definition
    PolygonShape tBox = new PolygonShape();
    tBox.setAsBox(0.5f,2);//meters
    //fixture definition
    fDef.shape = tBox;
    fDef.filter.categoryBits = B2DVariables.BIT_can;//colision type can step on ground
    fDef.filter.maskBits = B2DVariables.BIT_ground;
    toniBody.createFixture(fDef).setUserData("toni");

    //Toni's foot the Ground Sensor
    tBox.setAsBox(.2f , 0.2f, new Vector2(0, -2),0);
    fDef.shape = tBox;
    fDef.filter.categoryBits = B2DVariables.BIT_can;
    fDef.filter.maskBits = B2DVariables.BIT_ground;
    fDef.isSensor = true;
    toniBody.createFixture(fDef).setUserData("toniFoot");

    ground.dispose();
    tBox.dispose();
}
```

here is the part where a certain key trigger the movements

```
public  void handleInput(){

    //press W key aka Up key or BTNup
    if (RHInput.isDown(RHInput.BTNup)){

        if(rhcl.isPlayerOnGround()) {
            toniBody.setLinearVelocity(0,100);
            System.out.println("Toni jumps");
        }
    }


    if (RHInput.isDown(RHInput.BTNright)){
        rhcl.isPlayerOnGround();
        toniBody.setLinearVelocity(5,0);
        System.out.println("Toni walks right");
    }else {

        toniBody.setLinearVelocity(0,0);
    }


    if (RHInput.isDown(RHInput.BTNleft)){

        if(rhcl.isPlayerOnGround()) {
            toniBody.setLinearVelocity(-5,0);
            System.out.println("Toni walks left");
        }
        else {

            toniBody.setLinearVelocity(0,0);
        }
    }

            if (RHInput.isPressed(RHInput.BTNdown)){
        System.out.println("pressed s");
    }
    if (RHInput.isDown(RHInput.BTNdown)){
        System.out.println("holding s");
    }
}
```

other libGDX stuff

```
@Override
public void hide() {
    dispose();
}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    world.dispose();
    b2Dr.dispose();
}
```

}

The code is working. The character moves left and right at a linear velocity. But it doesn't jump very high and when it's falling it falls very slow. How can fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Simple way to make things fall faster is to increase gravity. Simple way to make player jump higher is to increase the impulse/velocity you give him to make him jump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... I´ve never used libgdx but been reading on how to implement the jump here http://obviam.net/index.php/getting-started-in-android-game-development-with-libgdx-tutorial-part-3-jumping-gravity-and-movement/ and checking your code for the physics you´ve added. I see you´ve got too much friction (as .5 or so) so the sprite should fall appearing to be floating. And jumps at 5 meters/second while gravity stands for 9.8m/second^2 in the world constructor so it will slow down in just one second not countin, again, the drag of the friction you´ve added... So, remove the friction, imagine, like in the tutorial.